# Iterative dividing by value specified by multiple dimensions dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe which includes population data across multiple years and geographies. Looks a bit like this:

```
df <- tibble(YEAR = c("2015", "2015", "2016", "2016", "2017", "2017", "2018", "2018"), 
           LOCATION = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"), 
           POPULATION = c(2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 6, 7, 9))

df
# A tibble: 8 x 3
YEAR  LOCATION POPULATION
<chr> <chr>         <dbl>
1 2015  a                 2
2 2015  b                 3
3 2016  a                 4
4 2016  b                 3
5 2017  a                 6
6 2017  b                 6
7 2018  a                 7
8 2018  b                 9
```

Now, I want to calculate the population for each location, relative to the first year (so population for 2015 = 1).

In effect, I want to divide the population for each year by the population for the first year (or another given year).

This would be fairly straightforward if the data were just grouped by year. I'd just call the specific first year (2015 in this reprex). I'd `mutate` and make my new variable `RELATIVE_POPULATION = POPULATION/(POPULATION[YEAR == "2015"])`  like this:

```
df_year <- df %>%
group_by(YEAR) %>%
summarise(POPULATION = sum(POPULATION)) %>%
mutate(RELATIVE_POPULATION = POPULATION/(POPULATION[YEAR == "2015"]))

df_year

# A tibble: 4 x 3
YEAR  POPULATION RELATIVE_POPULATION
<chr>      <dbl>               <dbl>
1 2015           5                 1  
2 2016           7                 1.4
3 2017          12                 2.4
4 2018          16                 3.2
```

But I want to do that for each location, to give an output which would look like this (so all location a populations are divided by the location a's 2015 population, and all location b populations are divided by location b's 2015 population)

```
YEAR  LOCATION POPULATION    RELATIVE_POPULATION
<chr> <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl> 
1 2015  a                 2   1
2 2015  b                 3   1
3 2016  a                 4   2
4 2016  b                 3   1
5 2017  a                 6   3
6 2017  b                 6   2
7 2018  a                 7   3.5
8 2018  b                 9   3
```

I think I can subset using `case_when` to do the calculation for each year, but I dont know how to specificy a value for the operation based on two other dimensions. I tried

```
df_relative <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    RELATIVE_POPULATION = case_when(
      LOCATION == "a" ~ POPULATION/(POPULATION[YEAR == "2015", LOCATION == "a"]),
      LOCATION == "b" ~ POPULATION/(POPULATION[YEAR == "2015", LOCATION == "b"])
    ))
```

but this returns an error  `Error in POPULATION[YEAR == "2015", LOCATION == "a"] :  incorrect number of dimensions`

So is it possible to specify two dimentions here, and if so, how?

One helpful person (@MikeMahoney218 on twitter) has cunningly suggested I create a second tibble, which has the 2015 values for each location, and I then join the two together, as follows:

```
original_pop <- df %>% 
  group_by(LOCATION) %>%
  filter(YEAR == 2015) %>% 
  select(LOCATION, INITIAL_POP = POPULATION)

df %>% 
  left_join(original_pop) %>%
  mutate(RELATIVE_POP = POPULATION / INITIAL_POP)

df
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  YEAR  LOCATION POPULATION INITIAL_POP RELATIVE_POP
  <chr> <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
1 2015  a                 2           2          1  
2 2015  b                 3           3          1  
3 2016  a                 4           2          2  
4 2016  b                 3           3          1  
5 2017  a                 6           2          3  
6 2017  b                 6           3          2  
7 2018  a                 7           2          3.5
8 2018  b                 9           3          3
```

This works (yay), but is there a way to do this without creating a second data frame? I could see this could become complex as code multiplies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a group by 'LOCATION', subset the 'POPULATION' where `YEAR` is 2015 and divide the POPULATION

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
    group_by(LOCATION) %>%
    mutate(RELATIVE_POPULATION = POPULATION/POPULATION[YEAR == 2015] ) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  YEAR  LOCATION POPULATION RELATIVE_POPULATION
  <chr> <chr>         <dbl>               <dbl>
1 2015  a                 2                 1  
2 2015  b                 3                 1  
3 2016  a                 4                 2  
4 2016  b                 3                 1  
5 2017  a                 6                 3  
6 2017  b                 6                 2  
7 2018  a                 7                 3.5
8 2018  b                 9                 3
```

NOTE: When we use `==`, make sure there is only a single match for each 'LOCATION' or else, have to get the first element i.e. `match(2015, YEAR)`

Comment: Well now I feel very silly. I don't think I'd realised I could `ungroup` in this lossless way! Thank you